# Oracle Data Provider for .NET with Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I have a problem with Oracle Data Provider for .NET. I have:

- just disinstalled and reinstalled new version of Oracle, I have now 12.1.0
- Visual Studio 2015
- Oracle Developer Tool for Visual Studio

I want to create a ASP.NET Web Application with Entity Framework 6.0. If I open one of my old projects or when I create a new one and download from Nuget Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccessEntityFramework this appears:

[image]

and if I click OK, I continue and create a model based on Oracle it always says that my EntityFramework is not correct for that provider even if I followed this [link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/NuGet/index.html#section2) or it crashes after setting the connection and click "Next".

[image]

[image]

What's wrong? Please help me..

Comment: Error message says "Oracle Data Provider for .NET". Maybe it means the **unmanaged** ODP.NET (`Oracle.DataAccess.dll`) which is different to the managed provider. Check you GAC with `gacutil.exe` tool.

Comment: did you get the answer yet??? if not let me know I will give you my answer

Comment: Did anyone found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Thats how I solved it:

Remove all folders wich names contains "Oracle" from:

1. Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\
2. Windows\assembly\

Then restart Visual Studio and it will work.

I used cmd in administrator mode to do that, because explorer or other file managers did not allow me to remove that folders.